# Comment flag for "+1" was declined

Tags: discussion, comment, flagging

When we leave comments, we see this message:

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

Also, [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) says:

> **When *Shouldn't* I comment?**
>
> Comments are not recommended any of the following:
>
> **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;

I saw [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456483/coin-tosses-and-probability/456484#456484):

> +1. Perfect answer.

I thought that it was just a "+1" or complimentary comment, so flagged it as "[too chatty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365)", but it was declined. I want to know why it was declined.

Comment: In a recent conference I attended in honor of one of the better known set theorists, each lecture began with the speaker saying some nice things about the honored mathematician. By the last two lectures the speakers opened up by saying that a lot of nice things were said by now, and they have nothing to add; so instead they will simply endorse what the others have said. The final speaker claimed that the endorsement option was already used, therefore he endorsed the previous speaker in his endorsement of the rest (and thus, by the transitive property...)

Comment: Why did I tell you this seemingly unrelated story? Well. Because sometimes it's good for people to know that an answer is endorsed by others. In particular when those others are already reputable in a certain topic. Now add to this the fact that MSE does not adhere strictly to the FAQ and Guidelines, and you got yourself a perfectly good reason not to delete this harmless comment.

Comment: But isn't the up arrow specifically for doing +1's? That doesn't tell you "who" is doing the +1's, but the questions on MSE are for the crowd and so I think it works itself out. I could see having a specific endorsement being more useful on Math Overflow if someone is well-known in the subfield or if the question was about a result related to someone's paper, but that kind of depth doesn't seem to happen (often) on MSE.

Comment: Now I feel inclined to specifically look for "+1, great answer, I learned a lot from that" comments by Asaf to some answer to an Axiom of Choice related question, say

Comment: I'm of course not the one who declined the flag, but it reminds me of when I reject edits to super old posts that just put math in Mathjax. Yeah, ideally the math would be typeset, but it's not really worth dragging a post from 2012 to the front page, just because the OP didn't typeset the quadratic equation they wanted to solve. It's just not important enough to warrant any action.

Comment: $+1$, good question.

Comment: Somewhat related: [What is the etiquette about leaving short thank-you comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/what-is-the-etiquette-about-leaving-short-thank-you-comments) Maybe also other discussion [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4284) might be of interest.

Comment: There's also the aspect of a well-reputed member putting their name out visibly to endorse an answer, which particularly for high profile questions is a nice way of saying "this is wheat, not chaff." Think of it as the opposite of a comment demonstrating an answer is wrong.

Comment: Such comments does not make any harm, so I think flagging them would create an unnecessary flood of notifications to moderators and will distract them from more important items. Also, I've read somewhere that such comments are periodically cleaned up anyway (would be grateful if someone will point to a link where this is written).